# How to generate text box on the scan image.. while after mouse click event

Tags: c#

I need to put text box on the scan image. but I need to put it the text box while I'm click mouse point  on the scan image. (it some thing like generate the text box in the mouse click event) I need code for it C#  or algorithm for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `TextBox` instance, set its `Left` and `Top` properties, and add it to the `Controls` collection of a panel.

Comment: no i gst want a code for it. i gust need to generate text box automatically  when i'm click the mouse point. (ex if i click on  vb form then need to generate texttbox automatically. not manually   )

Comment: We will not write your program for you.